# What does start-after in aws S3 ListObjectsV2 api mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In the [ListObjectsV2 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax) :

> **start-after**
> StartAfter is where you want Amazon S3 to start listing from. Amazon S3 starts listing after this specified key. StartAfter can be any key in the bucket.

It wasn't clear how is it listed. Is it by the time the file was added? Or by how the was sorted lexicographically?

Answer (score 9):

[ListObjectsV2](http://ListObjectsV2) api, objects are returned sorted in an `ascending order of the respective key names` in the list. (Not in the order of date)

and [StartAfter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax) means, it starts at StartAfter(including the passed key) and returns the keys from that key.

Answer (score 3):

`StartAfter` means ***lexicographically after***.

You're correct the doc definition is not worded clearly.

But [example 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_Example_3) shows a call with parameter `start-after=ExampleGuide.pdf`:

```
GET /?list-type=2&max-keys=3&prefix=E&start-after=ExampleGuide.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: quotes.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date: 20160430T232933Z
Authorization: authorization string
```

And the docs explain the behavior as follows:

> the request [will] retrieve up to three keys in the `quotes` bucket that start with `E` and occur ***lexicographically after*** `ExampleGuide.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that a bucket has date in **ISO** format as keys (or date as folder-name and within that folder we have rest of the data). e.g.

```
...
models/data/2022-12-25/
models/data/2022-12-26/
models/data/2022-12-27/
models/data/2022-12-28/
models/data/2022-12-29/
...
```

And we want to access the list from 26th onwards directly, we can achieve that by the below,

```py
# sample python snippet
# assumes your AWS token credentials are available in env

import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

bucket = "<your_bucket_name>"
prefix = "models/data/"

kwargs = {"Bucket": bucket, "Prefix": prefix, "Delimiter":"/", "StartAfter": "models/data/2022-12-25/"}

resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
resp["CommonPrefixes"]
```

## output

```
 [{'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-26/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-27/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-28/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-29/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-30/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2022-12-31/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2023-01-01/'},
  {'Prefix': 'models/data/2023-01-02/'},
])
```

As to why this works?

[ListObjectsV2](http://listobjectsv2/) API return the objects **sorted** in an **ascending** order of the **respective key names** (lexicographic-order) in the list. (**Not** in the modification / creation order of date as such)